# ¿como subir dato a campo con MD5 con php y mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 if(isset($_POST['regi'])){
$Nombre = $_POST['name'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];


mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Usuario 
(Nombre,Apellido,Email,Password) VALUES 
('$Nombre','$apellido','$email',MD5('$pass'))");
```

se sube todo menos el pass y no se si estoy poniendo mal para subir en MD5

Comment: "Sube todo menos el pass", te genera un error? Te deja el campo vacío? Que ocurre? Cual es el tipo de esa columna?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes calcular el checksum MD5 en php y enviarlo en la consulta:

```
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

mysqli_query($conect,"INSERT INTO Usuario (Nombre,Apellido,Email,Password) VALUES('$Nombre','$apellido','$email','$pass')");
```

el md5 tiene una longitud de 32...